# how do i create the small round delete buttons in interface builder?

Tags: ios, ios5, interface-builder

These ones. As seen in the Alarm app when you `Edit` and `Delete` an alarm.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not actually custom buttons.  They are a property of the delegate method: `- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.  as in:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

    }
```

After that, all you need to do is call `[tableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];`

Comment: Just a note, you call the setEditing:animated: by swiping left or right on the cell, or touching "edit" button at top (if exists).

Comment: Well... the first is true, but the second must be done manually by the programmer.  Not everything is magic!